# Cannot SCP a path with spaces from bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp

I have a bash script which generates an SCP command to execute. The relevant parts of the code look like this:

```
echo $COPY_CMD
$COPY_CMD
```

My output looks like this:

```
rascher@localhost:~/Desktop/video_final$ ./xfervids.sh 
scp "/media/My Book/PhotosVideos/Videos/18May2008Download/SD_VIDEO/PRG001/MOV056.MOD" rascher@192.168.1.101:./video_working/
rascher@192.168.1.101's password: 
"/media/My: No such file or directory
Book/PhotosVideos/Videos/18May2008Download/SD_VIDEO/PRG001/MOV056.MOD": No such file or directory
```

However, when I take line 2 of my output: `scp "/media/...`, copy it, and paste it into the terminal, it works.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried escaping the space in "My Book" (`"My\ Book"`), putting two `\` characters rather than one (`"My\\ Book"`) but I can't get this to behave consistently. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be excruciatingly careful when there are spaces in the path names.

In the context, you probably need:

```
eval $COPY_CMD
```

You don't need quotes around the variable this time.

Comment: Was completely unaware of the `eval` bash command. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should read [this discussion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) of how and why to avoid putting commands in variables and [this discussion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) of the security implications of `eval`.

One reason you may want to use variables in this way is to log or display the actions taken by a script. Problems occur with being able to properly quote or escape spaces, etc., as you have discovered. One way to do what you may want is to use `set -x` and `set +x` to turn this type of output on and off at various points in your script.

Comment: Probably overkill for my little home dvd-burning script, but good info nonetheless.